# Best practice for storing the chatbot's answers

Tags: node.js, botframework

My issue is that I don't know what is considered a good practice for storing the chatbot's answers. I do not wish to have the answer in plain text inside the `bot.dialog()` in code like this:

```
bot.dialog('Greeting', session => {
    session.endDialog('Hello, I'm a bot.');
});
```

... But instead fetch the answers from a database or a local file.

Since the bot is supposed to run in Azure, I've been looking at **Azure Cosmos DB with MongoDB**, but are there better alternatives? Given the simplicity of the database, would be a better practice to store the bot's answer in a **local JSON file** and store it in the same catalog as my `app.js` file?

The bot is supposed to be an FAQ bot, so the DB/file would mostly consist of answers that the bot is going to give for the different types of dialogs. There will most likely be no relation between the data.

Comment: How you should store data depends on a lot of factors. If this is not a user-facing app just yet, I'd recommend you *Keep It Simple*, and just store it on a local JSON file like you said.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides It is a user-facing app in the sense that it will be used on a website where end users can interact with the bot through a web chat.

Comment: In that case choose the DB that's most easy to set up and keep running. If MongoDB comes for free and fully managed with your Azure instance then go for that. Your data storage requirements are as simple as they get. It would be really easy to migrate your data to another DB tech should your data storage requirements change in the future. Don't sweat over this one.

Comment: Thank you. In terms of DB solutions, I think Azure Cosmos DB is the easiest solution so far, but I find it difficult to estimate the costs. If I end up with 1000 users using the bot simultaneously, then won't the RU/s skyrocket? If using a database, would it then be more suitable to do one huge query to fetch everything from the DB once `app.js` runs, store the query results in arrays and read from these?

Comment: I can't help you there unfortunately; I'm not familiar with their pricing model.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much for your input. I'll look into a database solution for storing the bot answers.

Comment: There's no "best practice" here as it would depend on the frequency of update, the cost, the technology you are confident with...

Comment: Why don't you use https://qnamaker.ai/?